# Type intersection in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming

I am trying to understand Type Relations in type script.
What is the intersection of the types denoted by the following two expressions:

```
{a:number}[] & {b:string}[]
```

Is that

```
{a:number,b:string}[]
```

?
Thanks,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
type T1={a:number}[];
type T2={b:string}[];
type intersection =T1&T2;
let z:intersection;
let z2=[{a:1,b:'2'}];
z=z2;
```

hence you are correct!

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, the documentation is not crystal clear as to the operator precedence in the type definition. But it is fairly easy to test:

```
type Z = { a: number }[] & { b: string }[];

let a: Z = [];
a = [{ a: 1, b: "q" }]; // Cannot assign because `b` does not exist in `{ a: number }`.
a = [{ a: 1 }]; // Cannot assign because `a` does not exist in `{ b: string }`.
a = [{b: "foo"}]; // Cannot assign because `b` does not exist in `{ a: number }`.
a = []; // Ok.

let x: { a: number, b: string }[] = a; // Cannot assign either.
```

The above shows that the hypothesis that it resolves to `{a:number,b:string}[]` is not correct. I had initially hypothesized that it would resolve to `({ a: number } | { b: string })[]`, but that's not correct either.

The intersection means "an array of elements where each element satisfies the type `{ a: number }` and at the same time satisfies the type `{ b: string }`. Since, `a` is not in the second type and `b` is not in the first, no element can satisfy the intersection. So you can only assign empty arrays to variables that are typed with the intersection.

To get the result you were hypothesizing, you'd need a different intersection:

```
type Z2 = { a: number, b?: string }[] & { a?: number, b: string }[];

let a2: Z2 = [];
a2 = [{ a: 1, b: "q" }];
```

This works as you expect because the first type in the intersection accepts elements that optionally have `b` and the 2nd type accepts elements that optionally have `a`.

Comment: Thank you Luis. Can you pleas explain the logic behind that? Doesn't  the intersection of these types supposed to fulfill both constrains? Can you give an example of a literal value of 'x2' . Thanks again.

Comment: I tried to run your code  and the line:
'let x: { a: number, b: string }[] = a;'
does not error.

Comment: It does error here, and does error in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/). Make sure you are using a recent version of TypeScript.

Comment: @David I've edited with a better investigation and explanation.